# Can I use default values based on previously passed positional arguments?

Tags: python, function, default-arguments

Is it possible to use a default variable based on previously passed positional arguments?

I'm trying to do something similar:

```
def ex(a, b=a+1):
    return a+b
```

Comment: it's not possible. you need to do that inside the function.

Comment: Fun fact: The `a` in `b=a+1` would be a global variable in existence at the point the function is defined, not the like named parameter `a` in the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that inside of the body, but not the signature.

```
def ex(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
       b=a+1
    return a+b
```